# React props are not inherited in Custom Next.js App component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I created custom next.js `App` component as a class(with intention to override `componentDidMount` function with initializing Google analytics).

```
class MyApp extends App {
    async componentDidMount(): Promise<void> {
        await initializeAnalytics();
    }

    render() {
        const {Component, pageProps} = this.props;

        return (
            <Container>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Container>
        );
    }
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es5", "es2015.promise", "dom"],
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "paths": {
            "@myapp/*": ["./node_modules"]
       }
   }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is
`error TS2339: Property 'props' does not exist on type MyApp`.

`props` field should be inherited from `App` component that is defined as:

```
export default class App<P = {}, CP = {}, S = {}> extends React.Component<P & AppProps<CP>, 
S> {
    static origGetInitialProps: typeof appGetInitialProps;
    static getInitialProps: typeof appGetInitialProps;
    componentDidCatch(error: Error, _errorInfo: ErrorInfo): void;
    render(): JSX.Element;
}
```

Why does compiler complain about missing `props` field on `MyApp` component? Shouldn't it be inherited from `App` component that extends `React.Component`?

Used versions:

- Typescript 4
- Next.js 10.0.0
- React 17.0.0
- @types/react 17.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add `"esModuleInterop": true` under `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json` file.

I'd also suggest you use `"jsx": "preserve"` to avoid other React-related issues.

Comment: It's correct. Thanks. What is the reason why it should be added? I have only upgraded next.js version from 6.1.2. to 10.0.0. and did nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

for you to use `this.props`, the props should be a method in the myApp class. therefore `this.props` doesnt exist as signaled by the compiler